# How to access external javascript methods / objects when using Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, jestjs

I am currently using JEST and use jasmine to test my reactJs application. There is a javascript file hosted on a different vendor site and I need access to the methods / objects in that external js file.

Note: The application loads this external js on page load and I have access to all methods in the application.

The object and methods are available here:

```
http://domain/scripts/vendor1/emd.js
```

I am trying to access an object (bbo), load it with necessary details and 
push it but I am not sure how to acccess

Sample function:

```
function pushEvent(obj){
 bbo.setVar( obj.param1,obj.value1);
 bbo.setVar(obj.param2,obj.value2);
 bbo.pushEvent(eventAction,eventParameters.eventCode,eventParameters);
}
```

Sample test:

```
 it("should call customLinkClick function",() => {
        reporting.pushEvent(obj);
        expect(reporting.pushEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I can download the JS and make it available locally for testing but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: use `jsdom.env` to pull in your external scripts, although I'm not sure why you wouldn't just require your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

To test that something is called on `bbo.pushEvent` you have to spy on it.

When `bbo` is available in the global name space in your app by loading an external file in your page you must create the object by yourself in the test.

```
global.bbo = {
  setVar: jest.fn(),
  pushEvent: jest.fn()
}
it("should call customLinkClick function", () = > {
  reporting.pushEvent(obj);
  expect(global.bbo.pushEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If you import `bbo` into your module then you have to mock it:

```
import bbo from 'bbo'
jest.mock('bbo', () = > ({
  setVar: jest.fn(),
  pushEvent: jest.fn()
}))
it("should call customLinkClick function", () = > {
  reporting.pushEvent(obj);
  expect(bbo.pushEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```